# Json node get asLocalDate

Tags: java, angularjs, json, jackson, localdate

Good day,

Please assist, I checked [Jackson JsonNode](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html)  but I can't seem to find what am looking for.

I need to know how to get `JsonNode` as `LocalDate`

```
// Example : I can get int value like :

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
final JsonNode data =mapper.readTree(json);
Int myNumberInt = data.get ("ngNumberInt").asInt();
```

How about `LocalDate`, how do I get it from `JsonNode`?

In my mind, am wishing there was

```
LocalDate dateCreated = data.get ("ngDate").asLocalDate();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JsonNode methods will only give you the JSON data types. However you can use your ObjectMapper instance to deserialize a LocalDate.

```
objectMapper.readValue(data, LocalDate.class)
```

You will need to include `jackson-modules-java8` if you haven't already. This includes a serializer/deserializer for Java's LocalDate.

Comment: Thank ao much for your response ..Okay am a lil confused am still new to spring... say I have $scope.mydata = { date: $scope.created } how do I extract date from this json ... is read value pointing to the whole json or specifically date object? If date obj how do I point and extract date from json ...

Comment: `.readValue` takes your `date` as argument. There are many approaches to reading JSON with Jackson. This problem isn't specific to Spring, but the Jackson library (that Spring utilizes). I suggest reading more about Jackson.

Comment: Okay what is data param in this regard?  Is data my date field ? @Gozard thank you in advance, I appreciate your responses

Comment: Yes, the `data` in my example is the same `data` as in your question (the JsonNode). Of course that will only work if the value of `data` is in a format the LocalDateDeserialized understands.

Comment: in 2023  "readValue " want  a "JsonParser" as parameter,   but "data"   is a "JsonNode",  for this reason the correct answer is   use "converValue"    (svarog answer is correct)

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`convertValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#convertValue(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Class)) method

```
LocalDate date = mapper.convertValue(data.get("date"), LocalDate.class);
```

As already stated above, the right java8 date-time deserializers must be registered on your object mapper

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late to the party, but you could also read as a string and then parse it:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(data.get ("ngDate").asText());
```

This will work if the date is ISO_LOCAL_DATE formatted, otherwise:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-MMM-yyyy");
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(data.get("ngDate").asText(), formatter);
```

Here the argument of `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern` can be any date formatting pattern. In the example it will parse date strings of the type "1-Aug-2009".

Answer (score 0):

in case if you are in need to convert epoch time in Json to localDateTime object, below approach can be followed as well.
Let's assume we have the JsonNode as below:

```
JsonNode createDate= {"Create_TS": {"$date": {"$numberLong": "1678353360304"}}}
```

below line will provide LocalDateTime:

```
 new Date(createDate.get(DOLLAR_DATE).get(DOLLAR_NUMBER_LONG).asLong());
```